# In Java, how do I check if a string consists of both letters and numbers, but only letters and numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I tried this:

```
private static void isLetterandNumberCombo(Tokens token) {
    if (token.getContents().matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+$")){
        token.setValid(false);
    }
}
```

but the input 123f45 still does not set the token to valid as I thought it would

Comment: Why would you think that lowercase `f` matches a regex that only allows uppercase letters? Either add lowercase letters to the character classes (e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`), or tell it to match case-insensitive, e.g. add [`(?i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) at beginning.

Comment: I am going to bet that `token.valid` is false by default.
Then, when you call `isLetterandNumberCombo`, `token.valid` will never be true, even if your regular expression is correct. Basically, don't forget to add an `else` branch, or store whether the contents are valid in a variable `isContentsValid` and call `token.setValid(isContentsValid)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine. You just need to add the case-insensitive flag (`(?i)`) to match lowercase letters. And `matches()` looks for a full match, so you don't need the anchors at the beginning and end:

```
(?i)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what OP is already doing (using lookaheads)?

Comment: The issue is case-sensitivity, as I mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245951/in-java-how-do-i-check-if-a-string-consists-of-both-letters-and-numbers-but-on#comment95316493_54245951).

Comment: Right. And the anchors are unnecessary when using `matches()`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl

```
private static boolean isLetterandNumberCombo(Tokens token) {
    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    return pattern.matcher(token.getContents()).matches();
}
```

You'll get back true or false if the token is valid.

Comment: *"if a string consists of **both** letters and numbers"* This answer doesn't check that at least one of each (letter vs number) is present.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
^[A-Za-z\d]*(([A-Za-z]\d)|(\d[A-Za-z]))[A-Za-z\d]*$
```

The idea is that a valid string will have either a letter followed by a number or the opposite somewhere, and other optional letters or numbers before or after.

Comment: Why is that better than what OP tried? It doesn't perform much better, so that's not it. Sure, it fixes the case-sensitivity issue by adding `a-z`, but you can do that to OP regex too, and you didn't even explain that that was the main issue (like I did in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245951/in-java-how-do-i-check-if-a-string-consists-of-both-letters-and-numbers-but-on#comment95316493_54245951)).

Answer (score -1):

A simple regex would do the job:

Change your function to:

```
private static void isLetterandNumberCombo(Tokens token) {
  token.setValid(token.getContents() != null && token.getContents().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sure it consists of both letters and numbers. And you forgot to check if `token` is null.